# Accessing the confidence parameters in IBM Watson nl-classifier

Tags: python, nlp, ibm-cloud, classification, ibm-watson

I'm building a web application where when i input a web page, it will get the textual content of web page, tokenize it and give each line to the trained classifier, what i want is to do something with those lines whose confidence parameters > 0.98. Below is an example taken from bluemix website:

```
     {
  "classifier_id": "10D41B-nlc-1",
  "url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier    /api/v1/classifiers/10D41B-nlc-1/classify?text=How%20hot%20wil/10D41B-nlc-1",
  "text": "How hot will it be today?",
  "top_class": "temperature",
  "classes": [
    {
      "class_name": "temperature",
      "confidence": 0.9998201258549781
    },
    {
      "class_name": "conditions",
      "confidence": 0.00017987414502176904
    }
  ]
}
```

Now in the above example, i want to something with class_name: temperature where confidence > 0.95.

```
 #if class.temperature.confidence > 0.98
     #do something with it
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

With your JSON return from your application NLP, you can join two conditions `true` in the same `if` to do that.

In this case:

```
if classes.classes_name === 'temperature' and classes.confidence > 0.95 
//do something
```

Python use `and` and `or` for logical operations conditions. The `and` will be check if the two conditions are `true`. And do something if yes.

Comment: It says that dict has no attribute 'class_name'. after i call the classifier.

Comment: I showed you the correct way to get the value you want, according to the return of your json in your question. You should check the return of your JSON, and walk the values you want, and from there make a condition.